# MYSQL : Undeclared variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedure the first parameter with static and it works well 
but when I but dynamic parameter it gives me an error Undeclared variable: limitvar
**1/procedure**

```
`DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `gestprospects`.`recClientsFiltre` $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `recClientsFiltre`(IN params text, in limitvar int , in offsetvar int )

BEGIN
SET @query := concat(concat("SELECT ... WHERE CONCAT(clients.id,'-') in (",params),") limit 10,10");
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query ;
  EXECUTE stmt  ;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END  $$

DELIMITER ;`
```

**2/procedure**

```
 DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `gestprospects`.`recClientsFiltre` $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `recClientsFiltre`(IN params text, in limitvar int , in offsetvar int )

BEGIN
SET @query := concat(concat("SELECT ... WHERE CONCAT(clients.id,'-') in (",params),") limit limitvar,offsetvar");
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query ;
  EXECUTE stmt  ;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END  $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you for your reply

Comment: I can't see a single difference between your two declarations. Please point at where the difference is, because playing Spot the Difference is tedious. Also, please clarify what you mean by "static" or "dynamic" (parameter). If this is related to the way you call the procedure, then including the call is a good idea.

Comment: Okay, I got it. See how I stripped your code to only show essential parts. Please try to provide [MCVE examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the litteral strings `limitvar` and `offsetvar` in your dynamic query, whereas you want to include their value.

```
@query := CONCAT(
    "SELECT ... WHERE CONCAT(clients.id,'-') IN (", params,")",
    " LIMIT ", limitvar, ", ", offsetvar);
```

Notice how you can [concatenate several strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in one call to `CONCAT()`;